# Remove numeric values from string

Tags: elixir

If given this string `'Cool1, let's g3et to work'` how can I return this value `Cool, let's get to work`? with Elixir?

I've been trying to get this with Regex with no lock so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`String.replace`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#replace/4):

```
String.replace("Cool1, let's g3et to work", ~r/\d/, "")
```

The `\d` means *any digit* (aka numeric value).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Regex.replace](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#replace/4):

`Regex.replace(~r/\d/, "Cool1, let's g3et to work", "")`